# Blazor - get relatedTarget on focus out event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I wan't to make something simmilar with this in Blazor. But I don't understand how can I get relatedTarget on focusout event.

Also seems FocusEventArgs in focus event in blazor doesn't support relatedTarget parameter
[aspnetcore-8.0#custom-event-arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-8.0#custom-event-arguments)

Does this limitation means that it is not recommended relay on relatedTarget parameter in Custom Argument Handler like shown in article above?

I've also tried implement this in Blazor using cancelation token + delay on hiding but it is also is not working well.

Any advise, thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="multiselect" onfocusin="focusin">
        <input class="search" type="search" placeholder="search..."></input>
        <div class="dropdown" tabindex="0">
            <select multiple class="select">
                <option>aaaa</option>
                <option>bbbb</option>
                <option>cccc</option>
            </select>
            <button class="btnOk" type="button">Select</button>
            <button class="btnCancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        const btnOk = document.querySelector('.btnOk');
        const btnCancel = document.querySelector('.btnCancel');
        const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
        const select = document.querySelector('.select');
        const search = document.querySelector('.search');
        const multi = document.querySelector('.multiselect');
        multi.addEventListener("focusin", focusin);
        multi.addEventListener("focusout", focusout);
        hide();
    
        function focusin(event) {
            show()
        }
    
        function focusout(event) {
            console.log(event.relatedTarget);
            if (needToHide1(event)) {
                hide();
            }
        }
    
        function needToHide(focusoutEvent) {
            return event.relatedTarget != select
                && event.relatedTarget != search
                && event.relatedTarget != dropdown
                && event.relatedTarget != btnOk
                && event.relatedTarget != btnCancel
        }
    
        function show() {
            dropdown.style.display = "block"
        }
    
        function hide() {
            dropdown.style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .multiselect {
            width: 300px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    
        .select {
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 20px;
    
        }
    
        .search {
            font-size: 20px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This looks like you want to do something when an input control loses focus.  Yes you can do that in Blazor  It would be helpful to know what and the type of data in the input to provide a relevant answer.

Comment: Just like what you found, Blazor events `Doesn't include support for relatedTarget.` I'm afraid we can hardly achieve your requirement. According to your codes, we can see you want to hide some elements which is getting focused. Since relatedTarget is not supported, we have to add focusin event on many other DOM, which is not a good idea...
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZmYm.png